# Passing String from Activity back to running Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-savedstate

There are a few posts about similar problems but I just don't get the wright answers and I hope that anyone can help me.

**Situation:** 
I have a `MainActivity` that contains several Fragments. In one Fragment I start a `CameraActivity` with an intent. When the user has taken the picture, the `CameraActivity` gets closed with `finish()` and we return back to the previous Fragment.

**Goal:**
I give the Picture a certain name and would like to pass this name from the `CameraActivity` to the Fragment.

**Problem:** 
Even though I call `finish()` in the CameraActivity and the screen returns back to the previous Fragment, the method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate)` is never called. Why is that?

Or how could I solve the problem otherwise?

Here is my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    // more code here

    String imageFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // some methods here
        finish(); // finish the current Activity and get back to previous Fragment
    }

    // more code here

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "onSaveInstanceState() called"); // is never called!
        outState.putString("imageFileName", imageFileName);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

And in the Fragment I do this:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    // more code here

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        // some methods here

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String imageFileName = getArguments().getString("imageFileName");
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "image filename: " + imageFileName);
        }

        return view;
    }

    // more code here
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at `startActivityForResults`. Here is a short example (haven't tried it but you will get the idea) :

**Fragment**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_PIC_TAKEN); // you may start an activity from another activity, not a fragment
```

**CameraActivity**

```
Intent results = new Intent();
results.putExtra("com;yourpackage.PIC_NAME", picName);
setResult(CameraActivity.RESULT_OK,results);
finish();
```

**Back to MainActivity** (since you called `getActivity()`)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RESULT_PIC_TAKEN) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle results = data.getExtras();
            String picName = results.getString("com.yourpackage.PIC_NAME");
            // code, and send what you want to the fragment
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Worked perfectly! The only thing I had to change: as first parameter you wanted of course to create the activity intent with the package context (not with the MainActivity class). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Start the CameraActivity using **startActivityForResult()**, once you get the string to pass back in your previous screen, just create an Intent that will contain that string, and in your MainActivity, implement:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Get the string from the intent, and pass it to your fragment.

**onSaveInstanceState** is used for other purposes.

Comment: I used the manual from @Gueg to solve the problem. But your approach was the same and it worked handsomely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!